# Accumulation Point Proof Topology Help

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that the following definitions are equivalent (both ways).

Def 1: 
$x$ is an accumulation point of $S$ if for all $\delta > 0$, $[(x - \delta , x) (x , x + \delta)] \cap S \not = \emptyset$

Def 2: 
$x$ is an accumulation point of $S$ if for all $\delta > 0$, $(x - \delta, x + delta) \cap S$ is infinite.

proof:
Suppose $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$,
then
  $[(x - \delta , x) (x , x + \delta)] \cap S \not =  \emptyset$.
If possible, we assume that there is set such that  is finite.
 $(x - \delta, x + \delta) \cap S$ is also finite.

Suppose $[(x - \delta , x) (x , x + \delta)] \cap S = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n\}$ where $n$ is a natural number.
Now we choose $S_1 = \min\{\vert x-x_1\vert, \vert x-x_2\vert, \ldots , \vert x-x_n \vert\}$  which is in the neighborhood of $x$.
This does not contain an element of $S$, which is contradiction of accumulation point.
Conversely, $(x - \delta, x + \delta) \cap S$ is  infinite. This shows that $[(x - \delta , x) (x , x + \delta)] \cap S \not =  \emptyset$ is also infinite.
This implies that $[(x - \delta , x) (x , x + \delta)] \cap S \not =  \emptyset$.

I am really confused. My professor tried to help me with this, but she confused me even more. I don't know if this is right or understand what this means. Why did she choose to prove that it was finite in the first part when we want infinite?

Comment: Ashley you assume the set is finite and derive a contradiction which tells us that the set can't be finite (i.e. it is infinite). Proofs by contradiction are rather standard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction

Comment: Word of advice: don't use the words "$x$ is an accumulation point" in your proof, because you are trying to prove that two different definitions of those words are equivalent. Instead use the words "$x$ satisfies Def 1" and "$x$ satisfies Def 2". Structure your proof in two separate parts: part A is to prove that if $x$ satisfies Def 1 then $x$ satisfies Def 2; and part B is to prove that if $x$ satisfies Def 2 then $x$ satisfies Def 1. I can see from what you wrote that you have jumbled Parts A and B up together; you have to do them separately.